# Runtime error in outlook macro - Item.senderName

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following macro;

```
Private WithEvents MySents As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set MySents = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub MySents_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim targetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set objNS = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
   If Item.SenderName = "Sender 1" Then
      Set targetFolder = objNS.Folders("Folder 1").Folders("Sent Items")
      Set newItem = Item.Copy
      newItem.Move targetFolder
   End If

   If Item.SenderName = "Sender 2" Then
      Set targetFolder = objNS.Folders("Folder 2").Folders("Sent Items")
      Set newItem = Item.Copy
      newItem.Move targetFolder
   End If
End If

End Sub
```

Last week this worked fine. Now when the macro runs I get a "Runtime error -2147221241 (80040107) The operation failed"

Looking at the debugger it fails on;

```
If Item.SenderName =
```

If I have a look at Items in the watch window most properties have "The operation failed" in the values.

Most strange about this is the fact that the message still gets copied anyway.

Can anyone see something silly I am doing?

Answer (score -1):

The [SenderName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869598.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property returns a String indicating the display name of the sender for the Outlook item. It is set after the mail item has been sent. New items (unsent) don't have this property set.

You may consider using the [SaveSentMessageFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868473.aspx) property which allows to set a Folder object that represents the folder in which a copy of the e-mail message will be saved after being sent. For example, you may handle the ItemSend event where you can set this property.

```
 Sub SetSentFolder()  
  Dim myItem As Outlook.MailITem 
  Dim myResponse As Outlook.MailITem 
  Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder 
  Dim mpf As Outlook.Folder 
  Set mpfInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
  Set mpf = mpfInbox.Folders.Add("SaveMyPersonalItems") 
  Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
  Set myResponse = myItem.Reply 
  myResponse.Display 
  myResponse.To = "Eugene Astafiev" 
  Set myResponse.SaveSentMessageFolder = mpf 
  myResponse.Send 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but he message has been sent as it is in the sent items folder. Point been that the macro does what it needs to do even after it throws the error. The sent item still gets copied to the other folders.. I just don't get why it was fine last week.

Comment: Right, now I am very confused.. If I add "MsgBox ("Message Moved")" to the end,just before the endsub, the runtime error is not thrown... What is going on here? I forgot to say that I get the runtime error on multiple computers. Thanks

Comment: What line of code generates an error? Did you try to debug the code?